# Vuejs router updating hash values without reloading or rerendering entire page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an accordion component with a few tabs. Its tabs should be listening to the #hash url.

For example `localhost:8080/page#tab1,tab2` should lead to tab1 and tab2 being opened.

Now when I click/toggle tab3, I can push the tab to the url through the router like this: `this.$router.push('#tab1,tab2,tab3')`. But this causes the window to scroll up.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This results in `TypeError: this.$router.append is not a function`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's used something like `<router-link :to="link" append></router-link>`